# C++ class : undefined reference to method

Tags: c++

I have some class called gSprite that allows easy manipulation of image , manipulation and etc. As I completed some of it's functions and fixed all errors, I tried to use it and got others.
Here is class custom creators

```
gSprite *  crGSprite(sf::Sprite * sprsource){
return new gSprite(sprsource);
}
gSprite *  crGSprite(sf::Sprite * sprsource,int sx, int sy){
return new gSprite(sprsource,sx,sy);
}
gSprite *  crGSprite(std::vector<sf::Sprite> spr,int sx,int sy){
return new gSprite(spr,sx,sy);
}
```

All creators are just construct new object and return reference to it.
Then I have function for storing data about all files and create them in other file, that can reach these creators:

```
gSprite * loadsprite(string path)
{
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Texture tex;
    tex.loadFromFile(path);
    sprite.setTexture(tex);
    gSprite * gspr = crGSprite(&sprite);
    addGSprite(gspr);
    return gspr;
}
```

And all fine. BUT. Class also contains some functions.For some reason when I try to execute update(), it works, but when I trying to execute setPosition() it fails with "undefined reference to `gSprite::setPosition(int,int)`.
Here is these two functions and .hpp file:

```
void update()
{
    sprite = anim_sprites[num];
    sprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(x,y));
    return;
}
```

and

```
void setPosition(int nx,int ny)
{
    x=nx;
    y=ny;
    return;
}
```

hpp:

```
#ifndef Sprites_H_
#define Sprites_H_

extern sf::RenderWindow * windowsrc;
class gSprite {
    int x;
    int y;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    std::vector<sf::Sprite> anim_sprites;
    sf::Vector2f size;
    bool anim;
    int num;
public:
    gSprite(sf::Sprite * sprsource);
    gSprite(sf::Sprite * sprsource,int sx, int sy);
    gSprite(std::vector<sf::Sprite> spr,int sx,int sy);
    void setSize(float x, float y);
    void resize(float x,float y);
    void scale(float x,float y);
    void draw_s();
    void update();
    void move(int nx,int ny);
    void setPosition(int nx,int ny);
};

gSprite * crGSprite(sf::Sprite * sprsource);
gSprite * crGSprite(sf::Sprite * sprsource,int sx, int sy);
gSprite * crGSprite(std::vector<sf::Sprite> spr,int sx,int sy);
void addGSprite(gSprite * sprtsource);
void drawGSprites();

#endif /* Sprites_H_ */
```

**I declare methods inside class declaration**

Comment: Also, I call it by reference to object like: `spr->setPosition(100,100);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
void setPosition(int nx,int ny)
{
    x=nx;
    y=ny;
    return;
}
```

you're defining a standalone function that's not part of any class.  To implement the member function declared in the `gSprite` class, you have to write

```
void gSprite::setPosition(int nx,int ny)
{
    x=nx;
    y=ny;
    return;
}
```

Comment: I just described it wrong way. I declare functions inside class declaration. Like in .hpp but like function. I edited post to correct my mistake

Comment: Your class definition (the `class gSprite { ... }`) contains a declaration of the `setPosition(int, int)` member function, but you haven't written a defintion of that function.  You've written a definition of some *other* function that also happens to be called `setPosition(int, int)`, but isn't part of the `gSprite` class.

Comment: Declaring it in the class is not enough, you also need to specify the class in the definition. Otherwise, you end up having a standalone function AND an unimplemented method.

Comment: Remember that you can have member functions with the same name in different classes.  You could have a `foobar` class that also has a `setPosition(int, int)` member function.  That's why when you define a function, you have to say which class (if any) it's a member of — so that you can write separate defintions for `gSprite::setPosition(int, int)` and `foobar::setPosition(int, int)`, with different code for each.

Comment: Figured it out: I thought that classes have prototypes like functions, and declared class two times: in .hpp without defining and in .cpp with defining

Comment: But why compilator don't says anything about update() is still mystery

Comment: NB:  your `class gSprite { ... }` is a class *definition* — it tells the compiler what the class's members are.  A class *declaration* just tells the compiler that the class exists, without describing its members: `class gSprite;`

Comment: The reason why you're not getting an undefined-reference error for `update()` is that you don't appear to be *calling* `update()` from anywhere.  There are no references to it, so the linker doesn't need to find a definition of it.